# what's the volume of T(V)?

Tags: calculus

Consider V:{(x,y,z)|x^2+y^2<=1, 0<=z<=2} and the transform T:(x,y,z) to (x,y+tan(az),z)， where a belongs to (0,pi). What's the volume of T(V)?
Please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that $a \in (0,\pi) \setminus \{  \frac{\pi}{2} \}$, otherwise $T$ is not defined.

$DT(x) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & a \sec^2 (az) \\
0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$, hence $|\det DT(x) | = 1$.

Note that $V$ is compact. With $f = 1$, the change of variables formula gives
$$ \int_{T(V)} 1(x) dx = \int_V 1(T(x)) |\det DT(x) | dx $$
Hence $m(T(V)) = m(V)$. It is straightforward to compute $m(V) = 2 \pi$.